# Relative Tab Index

Tags: html

I'm using tab indexes on my navigation to allow users to tab through that content. The problem I am having is the third and fourth ( out of six ) open a modal. Once that modal is open The user must tab through the rest of the navigation to get to the fields in the modal. I would like to have the modal's forms/elements capture all the tabbing before returning to navigation if not stop it from moving back to the nav elements until the modal is closed. Is there a simple way to force the next tab to jump to the first field on the modal with out using javascript? It seems really simple but I think some how I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

```
<nav>
    <a tabindex="1" href="#">A</a>
    <a tabindex="2" href="#">A</a>
    <a tabindex="3" href="#" onclick="$('.b').show();">A</a>
    <a tabindex="4" href="#">A</a>
    <a tabindex="5" href="#">A</a>
    <a tabindex="6" href="#">A</a>
    <a tabindex="7" href="#">A</a>
</nav>

<a tabindex="3" href="#" class="b" >B</a>
<a tabindex="4" href="#" class="b" >B</a>
<a tabindex="5" href="#" class="b" >B</a>
<a tabindex="6" href="#" class="b" >B</a>
```

Here is a small non-working example of what I am trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/jeffpowrs/KgHtg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/KgHtg/3/

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu1').click(function() {
        $('.b').show();
        var currentIndex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        var greater = $('nav a').filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr('tabindex') > currentIndex;
        }).each(function() {
            $(this).attr('tabindex', parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'), 10)+4);
        });
    });
});
```

You can just update the value in the tabindex attribute. You'll have to work with this to get the update to happen on the submenu open/close but you should get the gist of where this is going.